# Autodelete podcasts

Tags: 8.1, podcast

At some point in the past (perhaps when I was downloading podcasts to the phone memory, instead of an SD card), podcasts which I had subscribed to (and hence got downloaded automatically) also deleted automatically after I had listened to them (or when they expired according to the preferences of the publisher).  However, the autodelete now doesn't happen, and I have to delete podcasts manually.

Is there a way to make podcasts autodelete after they've been listened to?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open podcasts app.
2. Open in-app settings.

[image: podcast app settings]

3. Choose how much episodes you want to keep.
4. The older ones will be auto deleted.
5. Currently there is no option to delete podcasts once you have listened, in the built-in podcast app.

Comment: Hmm, I've got this option checked already and it doesn't seem to have the desired effect

Comment: @ChrisW Did you check the *Also Apply to existing subscriptions* check box before saving

Comment: yeh - I've just checked that all the individual series have the same settings as the default to see if that might be the cause

Comment: @ChrisW I couldn't be sure why this is not working for you. It had worked for me nicely, deleting all except the latest podcast.